# Pyspark - Transpose distinct row values to a column header where ill insert values from the same row I transposed but different column

Tags: python, dataframe, dynamic-pivot, pyspark-pandas

This is the table I want to transpose

[image: 1]

I created a list of the distinct values at DESC_INFO using this:
`columnsToPivot = list(dict.fromkeys(df.filter(F.col("DESC_INFO") != '').rdd.map(lambda x: (x.DESC_INFO, x.RAW_INFO)).collect()))`

And then I tried to map the RAW_INFO values into the matching columns with this:

```
for key in columnsToPivot:
  if key[1] != '':
    df = df.withColumn(key[0], F.lit(key[1]))
```

It happens that I just wrote all rows with the same value when I want to fill the RAW_INFO where the table matcher the values mapped with the same 'PROCESS', 'SUBPROCESS' AND 'LAYER'.

This is the map I expect at the end.

[image: 2]

The **blue lines** mean the transpose I have already achieved.
The **red lines** mean the data I need to fill matching the condition **shadowed in yellow**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df_new=df.filter(df['Desc_info']!='').groupBy('Layer','Process','Subprocess').pivot('Desc_Info').agg(first('Raw Info'))
```

Comment: Your code is working and it could be helpful, but, its deleting data while it does the pivot.
The table has some extra data that I want to transpose later as well, ill insert an screenshot below.
I want to transpose the rows about columns ('COLUMN', COLUMN_DATA' and 'COLUMN_DATA_VALUE') and when I execute the command above, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This shows the extra data that I have hidden on the first 2 screenshots.]
Thats becouse of this columns that I want to repeat the data from **DESC_INFO** and **RAW_INFO**

Comment: can't these extra columns be added in the group by clause,

groupBy('Layer','Process','Subprocess','COLUMN', COLUMN_DATA','COLUMN_DATA_VALUE')